# Switch from manual updating to NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My whole app is pretty much table views. Im not using a `nsfetchedResultsController`, so i am doing all of the tableView work myself. But my main question is:

If i allow my cells to be reordered, they dont stay in the order that i move them to, if i switch pages. So if i convert my tableViews to use `NSFetchedResultsController` would this fix the problem? I have searched and searched for a solution to save the NSarray order to core data or to NSUserDefaults but i cannot find a solution/tutorial or really anything on the subject for that matter. So if anyone could help me out that would be great! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: They don't stay in that order because you probably didn't update the order of items in your array, which you're supposed to do.

Comment: right, i have been told to either do that, or to save the order of the array. I cannot find anything on that, except people giving that same answer. I have searched for about 3 hours and i cannot find the answer. If you know of any tutorial i would be very appreciative!

Comment: No, I don't know any tutorials -- look at the section on reordering rows in Apple's documentation in "Table View Programming Guide for iOS"

Comment: Core Data also supports ordered relationships now. This might help you http://ashfurrow.com/blog/running-time-of-nsorderedset-in-ordered-to-many-core-data-relationships